# jQuery ajax request relative path

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm implementing a jQuery plugin that needs to use some html markup. I try to load the html code by ajax request but the problem I'm facing is it doesn't accept relative paths. I can't specify the path from root folder because I need this plugin to run as library and I don't know on which path the user of the library will put the library folder.

If it's not possible to do something like that what is the best possible workaround. Personally I don't like to put the html markup inside of the javascript code.

**UPDATE**
html import seems to solve my issue but unfortunately most of the browsers don't support this future yet. Here is a link that describes what html import is http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

Comment: Sure it accepts relative paths...

Comment: The relative path does need to be a file that's still under the web-accessible directory on the web server. Say you're at "C:\apache\htdocs\index.html"; you obviously can't enter "../conf/httpd.conf" to get "C:\apache\conf\httpd.conf" because htdocs is the root accessible area. Otherwise, relative paths should work.

Comment: I've tested it with "./test.html" and "test.html" and the network request would be www.domain.com/test.html even if the test.html and the javascript that I make request from is inside of the lib or what ever folder. Benjamin Gruenbaum

Comment: My lib folder is accessible @Katana314 and the relative path doesn't work

Comment: Does the direct request work? Can you enter the URL in your web browser and get the document? If that works, could you try opening up the Network tab in the developer tools in your browser, and see if you can see what exact URL is being requested?

Comment: @Katana314 yes I can access the files by direct URL. I can access the files if I specify absolute url. In the console I get "GET http://localhost:4000/test.html 404 (Not Found)"

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to specify an absolute path. jQuery.ajax will accept a relative path. Just be sure to prefix the path with '/'.

The result here is that it will access the relative path of whatever domain/host the script is currently executing.

Alternatively, you can also make the host configurable within your app.

Comment: "The result here is that it will access the relative path of whatever domain/host the script is currently executing." exactly that is my problem. I want it to be relative to the current running javascript code.